# Looping over async operations

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am making a query on Sequelize, then want to run a query based on each user in the db. I am not sure how to turn this forEach loop into a Promise, so I can perform operations after the forEach loop is finished....

```
users.forEach(user => {
  let userHideCount = 0
  Comment_List.findAll({
    where: {user_id:user}, attributes: ['user_id','cid'], include: [
      {model: Comment, attributes: ['verb','created_time']}
    ],
    order: [[ Comment, 'created_time', 'DESC' ]],
  })
  .then(cl => {
    cl.forEach(comment => comment.get({plain:true}).comments[0].verb === 'hide' ? userHideCount++ : null)
    hiddenCounts[user] = userHideCount
  })
})
```

Or maybe there is a better way to go about this... any help is greatly apprecaited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Promise.all` and turn the `forEach` into a `map` that returns the promises. Eg:

```
var userPromises = users.map(user => {
  let userHideCount = 0
  return Comment_List.findAll({
    where: {user_id:user}, attributes: ['user_id','cid'], include: [
      {model: Comment, attributes: ['verb','created_time']}
    ],
    order: [[ Comment, 'created_time', 'DESC' ]],
  })
  .then(cl => {
    cl.forEach(comment => comment.get({plain:true}).comments[0].verb === 'hide' ? userHideCount++ : null)
    hiddenCounts[user] = userHideCount
  })
})

// Then, sometime later:
Promise.all(userPromises).then(() => {
    // Do stuff.
})
```